# Recover corrupted aspx file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, recover

My system crashed whilst I was in the middle of updating an .aspx page in visual studio 2010. When I rebooted my PC and started visual studio again the .aspx file was still there, but when I clicked to open it in solution explorer notepad opened and a blank file was displayed. Looking at the file in windows explorer the file still has it's size of 31Kb, My file content was replaced with some white space characters

Any suggestions to how I might recover this file? I've spent a 4-5  days of work,  with no backup - arrh! any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Old post, sharing my experience :D

I faced the same problem with a file today and overcame it successfully. :D

Felt freaking heavenly after getting my file back ... :D \m/ :D

Here is the solution. Actually, there can be two types of solution of recovering corrupted files I found.

> **Scenario:** Your file is corrupted (ie. null or space everywhere in the file while the size is ok)
>
> **Solution #1:** Using file recovery software.
>
> File recovery softwares can recover a file when it is already deleted.
>   In our scenario, your file is not deleted but corrupted. So how to use
>   the software in this case!!!!
>
> - Just delete your file
> - Try to recover your deleted files with popular file recovery softwares
>
> And voila ... it is recovered ... :D
>
> The recovery software I used is [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). Worked perfectly.
>
> **Solution #2:** If its a web content, like CSS/Javascript/html etc.
>
> You can collect the last working copy of the file from browser cache,
>   IF and ONLY IF you hadn't opened the corrupted webpage in that brower.

The thought that help me finding the first solution is from

**Mark Twain** - "Never argue with stupid people, they will drag you down to their level and then beat you with experience."

While I was thinking how to use this recovery software, I thought about this quote and said myself "LETS DRAG THE FILE DOWN TO THE LEVEL, WHERE RECOVERY SOFTWARE CAN RECOVER" ... :D

Comment: i am facing the same problem with the questioner. I followed your steps but recuva isn't detecting my deleted file :(